# A forEach function that supports stepping

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I want to iterate through a list of items in steps of 2. This would be done like this:

```
for (i in 0..users.lastIndex step 2) {
   val user = users[i]
}
```

This is okay, but it would be nicer if there was something even simpler like a forEach. But a forEach doesn't provide stepping. Is there an API that does allow you to provide stepping in a forEach fashion? Something like this:

```
users.forEach(step = 2) { user ->
   
}
```

Comment: `for (i in users.indices step 2) { }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's no such function in the Kotlin standard library. However, it's not too difficult to create your own extension function:

```kotlin
inline fun <T> List<T>.forEachStep(step: Int = 1, action: (T) -> Unit) {
    /*
     * May want to have an iterator-based solution as well for lists that
     * don't support random access. You could choose which solution to
     * use based on 'if (this is RandomAccess)'.
     */
    for (i in indices step step) {
        action(get(i))
    }
}
```

Which you can then use on any `List`.

```kotlin
val users: List<User> = ...
users.forEachStep(step = 2) { user ->
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `forEach` to replace a for loop is against the Kotlin [coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#loops), which also comes with a reminder to keep performance considerations in mind when chaining higher-order functions. Worth keeping in mind before you start going crazy with extension functions :-)

> Prefer using higher-order functions (`filter`, `map` etc.) to loops.
> Exception: `forEach` (prefer using a regular `for` loop instead, unless
> the receiver of `forEach` is nullable or `forEach` is used as part of a
> longer call chain).
>
> When making a choice between a complex expression using multiple
> higher-order functions and a loop, understand the cost of the
> operations being performed in each case and keep performance
> considerations in mind.